# Vue 2 devServer proxying does not work for websocket

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have simple web server in python running for example on 127.0.0.1:8080.
I can serve http-requests and web sockets.
This is example of server routes.

```js
...
web.route('*', '/ws', ws_handler),
web.route('*', '/api/some_url', http_handler)
...
```

And I have frontend part of my application in Vue 2 JS.
I set up `vue.config.js` file for proxying dev server.

```js
const host = "127.0.0.1"
const port = 8080

devServer: {
  proxy: {
    "/api": {
      target:`http://${host}:${port}/`,
      secure:false
    },
    "/ws": {
      target:`ws://${host}:${port}/`,
      ws:true,
      secure:false,
      changeOrigin:true
    }
  }
}
```

When I make http requests, for example

```js
let res = await axios.get('/api/some_url');
```

everything works fine, but if I want to set up websocket connection

```js
soc = new WebSocket('/ws');
```

I got error

```
Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL '/ws' is invalid.
```

For websockets my settings does not work.

Connection sets up and everything works fine if full address is provided.

```js
soc = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8080/ws');
```

I have read many articles and had no success for resolve my issue - how can I do proxying websocket connection for Vue JS dev server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instantiate your WebSocket as `ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/ws');`